# Enabling HTML tags in this JS Code

Tags: javascript

I use this code for creating Summary of the Blog Posts at my blog Gadgetcage.com, In this JS code HTML tags are disabled by the author, I would like to remove that disabling HTML tag function in this Code. Please help me!!

```
function removeHtmlTag(strx,chop){ 
    if(strx.indexOf("<")!=-1)
    {
        var s = strx.split("<"); 
        for(var i=0;i<s.length;i++){ 
            if(s[i].indexOf(">")!=-1){ 
                s[i] = s[i].substring(s[i].indexOf(">")+1,s[i].length); 
            } 
        } 
        strx =  s.join(""); 
    }
    chop = (chop < strx.length-1) ? chop : strx.length-2; 
    while(strx.charAt(chop-1)!=' ' && strx.indexOf(' ',chop)!=-1) chop++; 
    strx = strx.substring(0,chop-1); 
    return strx+'...'; 
}

function createSummaryAndThumb(pID){
    var div = document.getElementById(pID);
    var imgtag = "";
    var img = div.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var summ = summary_noimg;
    if(img.length>=1) { 
        imgtag = '<span style="float:left; padding:0px 10px 5px 0px;"><img src="'+img[0].src+'" width="'+img_thumb_width+'px" height="'+img_thumb_height+'px"/></span>';
        summ = summary_img;
    }

    var summary = imgtag + '<div>' + removeHtmlTag(div.innerHTML,summ) + '</div>';
    div.innerHTML = summary;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to avoid calling the function:  removeHtmlTag(div.innerHTML,summ).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow html, just create a new function consisting of

```
function truncateSummary(strx, chop) {
  chop = (chop < strx.length-1) ? chop : strx.length-2; 
  while(strx.charAt(chop-1)!=' ' && strx.indexOf(' ',chop)!=-1) chop++; 
  strx = strx.substring(0,chop-1); 
  return strx+'...'; 
}
```

and change the var summary line to

```
var summary = imgtag + '<div>' + truncateSummary(div.innerHTML,summ) + '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm don't know too much about JavaScript, but shouldn't this do the trick.

```
function createSummaryAndThumb(pID){
    var div = document.getElementById(pID);
    var imgtag = "";
    var img = div.getElementsByTagName("img");
    if(img.length>=1) { 
        imgtag = '<span style="float:left; padding:0px 10px 5px 0px;"><img src="'+img[0].src+'" width="'+img_thumb_width+'px" height="'+img_thumb_height+'px"/></span>';
    }

    var summary = imgtag + '<div>' + div.innerHTML + "..." + '</div>';
    div.innerHTML = summary;
}
```

Just use that and delete the removeHtmlTag function